# Glass material is dark on cornea of eye

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials

I've tried to research this, but none of the solutions I found worked for me. I'm really just experimenting with modeling and materials, so this isn't really suppose to be anything.

Here's the link to the .blend file:

[image]

I'm trying to create an eye using the cycles nodes. From following tutorials, my understanding is that I should have an inner sphere with the color materials, and an outer sphere with a glass shader on it to give the eye some shininess and reflectivity. Unforturnately, the glass material looks very dark. If I pull the cornea sphere out of the socket, it looks like a perfectly decent glass ball, but when it's in the socked, it's incredibly dark. I'll attach images of the rendered version and of my nodes setup. [image: rendered version] [image: nodes setup]

Comment: If you want to provide files for review, please use exclusively http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and post the link into your question. Files from other file services tend to "vanish" over time which makes your question and possible answers eventually less useful.

Comment: [<img src="http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=2075" />](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/2075/)

Comment: You can use the edit link below your post to paste the link into your original question. I fixed it for you.

Comment: Try mixing the glass shader with a transparent shader, usually helps a bit. Also change the color of the glass material from the default 'white' to a true pure white

Comment: I'm already mixing it with a transparent shader, with 'is shadow ray' and 'is reflection ray' as the factor. I had already changed the color to pure white, but it still looks like it does in the image.

Answer (score 3):

I had accidentally applied the glass material to the inner eye as well as the outer eye. It was dark because there was nothing for the light to bounce off. It looks much better now.[image: Fixed]